# Django generates 'WHERE ... BETWEEN ...' sentences?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

Actually, somewhere in the view:

```
dif = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - dif
ex = Fact.objects.filter(fecha_fact__lte=today ,fecha_fact__gte=yesterday )
```

It results to this SQL Query:

```
SELECT `facts_fact`.`id` ...
FROM `facts_fact` 
WHERE (`facts_fact`.`fecha_fact` >= 2009-09-21 AND `facts_fact`.`fecha_fact` <= 2009-09-22 )
```

There is a way to make Django do a WHERE BETWEEN sentence instead >= <= ?

:) thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried [`range`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#range)?

```
Fact.objects.filter(fecha_fact__range=(yesterday, today))
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know, but maybe (gte / lte ):

```
q1 = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
q2 = q1.exclude(pub_date__gte=datetime.now())
q3 = q1.filter(pub_date__gte=datetime.now())


q = Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith="What")
q = q.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.now())
```